# mercurial repository problem in redmine after upgrade "Entry and/or revision doesn't exist in the repository."

Tags: mercurial, redmine

I've just upgraded to the newer version of redmine (1.1.3) , after that all my mercurial repositories shown "Entry and/or revision doesn't exist in the repository."

something goes wrong, but what?

the permissions, settings and paths of repositories are the same.

thanks

PS: I've tried to create a new repository, and a new project too without success

Comment: resolved,I've just restarted the webapp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resolved,I've just restarted the webapp